# Detecting the mobile Browser making request call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a website.The Compulsion is that it should work on Iphone,Androids,Samsung Galaxy S/S2,Ipad, Samsung Galaxy Tab,etc. and must give the Same experience. Is there a way to detect what mobile browser is making the request for page and accordingly apply the CSS made for it using Jquery?
I would like to strictly use HTML5, Jquery, CSS3 only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your default stylesheet at the top of the page

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css">
```

Extend the jquery library to detect iphone/ipad

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery.extend(jQuery.browser,
      {SafariMobile : navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iP(hone|ad)/i) }
 );
 </script>
```

then check to see if the browser is of type and change the stylesheet accordingly

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        if($.browser.SafariMobile){
          $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "iphone.css"});
        }
      })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need CSS3 media queries to detect device widths, resolutions and orientations. A good starting point for you to use is Mobile Boilerplate - http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile

Comment: Thanks for the Hint.I'll go through instructions. Any further Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do in the general case is extremely hard.
It is not the browser detection that is the problem. The browser can be detected using any of the methods given above. But getting the screens widths and sizes and the actual capabilities of HTML support is much harder.

There is an open-source project called as [WFURL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) that maintains a database of all supported devices and their abilities to integrate and can be used.

What we do is use a framework like [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) that automatically gives a similar look and feel in various phones. This framework is however still very raw.

The way most sites like Mercedes Benz, ebay, mtv india, google etc. do this is by using something like [NetBiscuits] (http://www.netbiscuits.com/) to design their mobile sites. This way they write the code once(albeit in BiscuitML) and NetBiscuits does the job of detecting the mobile device and optimizing the site. For examples check out this [link](http://www.netbiscuits.com/customers) customers using NetBiscuits.

NetBiscuits might not be the only framework out there that does this(I know IBM provides a solution as part of their websphere portal server) , however is the most popular I know of.

Answer (score -2):

You can use following statements to get information about browser.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

OR

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

Comment: is get_browser an in-built Function? If not what is it that is required to make it work.It did not work!!

Comment: -1 There is nothing about PHP here. You can't assume he's using PHP - it's not the only server-side web language in the world.